# Get the current location on iphone

Tags: iphone, gps, core-location, cllocationmanager

how many ways we can get current location on iphone application?I have got this with using of cllocationmanager(corelocation framework)

Is there anyother way to get the current location?

Comment: Why aren't you using the way you know?

Comment: as far as I know, this is the most used and most well documented way there is out there. The API is rather well documented too.

Answer (score 1):

There may be 3rd party location libraries, but they are all just wrappers for CoreLocation. SimpleGeo is a pretty common location library. But you are more than likely better off just using Apple's implementation of CoreLocation as it is widely documented and pretty straight forward to use.